# cs50 filter "blur" pset4

Tags: c, filter, cs50, blur

This code for cs50 filter "blur" compiles, but when I run it, it says, `index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width].'`. I somewhat understand what it means, but I dont know why its saying that I exceeded the array limit.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int counter = 0;
    int sumGreen = 0;
    int sumRed = 0;
    int sumBlue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++)
            {
                for (int m = j - 1; m <= j + 1; m++)
                {
                    if (k >= 0 && m >= 0 && k <= height && m <= width)
                    {
                        sumGreen += image[k][m].rgbtGreen;
                        sumBlue += image[k][m].rgbtBlue;
                        sumRed += image[k][m].rgbtRed;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sumGreen / counter;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sumBlue / counter;
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = sumRed / counter;
            counter = 0;
            sumGreen = 0;
            sumBlue = 0;
            sumRed = 0;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: @kiner_shah what does static/dynamic array mean and how could I do something like that? And I'm not sure if it works for smaller images. I was provided only 4 images of the same size.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I didn't read the code correctly. The error is using `height` and `width` in `image[height][width]`. You cannot do that! If you are given any constraints like "Image can be of max. size 100x100", then you declare the `image` array as `image[100][100]`.

Comment: @kiner_shah I tried doing that but it didnt change anything. Still says "helpers.c:53:37: runtime error: index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [600]'"

Comment: Don't put small value like 600, try putting 1000 or 2000! Remember, images can be a lot bigger - like 1920x1080, 1920x720, etc. There can be larger resolution images. There can be images of size > 6000 too!

Comment: @kiner_shah I made it large like you said and the old error was removed, but now when I run it, the program constantly pastes, "UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL" and its not stopping.

Comment: @Yunnosch probably answered to your problem. That DEADLYSIGNAL seems like an Address Sanitizer's output. It seems you are accessing illegal memory in your code because of which there can be undefined behavior. You need to correct your code.

Comment: I think you don't need the two inner most loops iterating over `k` and `m`. You can access the previous row's or column's data simply by using `image[i - 1][j]` or`image[i][j - 1]`.

Comment: @kiner_shah if I did something like that, the code would just be a long list of lines like: `sumGreen += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen; 
sumBlue += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
sumRed += image[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
sumBlue += image[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;`

etc.

Comment: But it will do your job! Try it out. Comment those two inner for loops and try this method!

Comment: @kiner_shah It worked! Thank you so much! You helped me a lot!

Comment: Great to hear that! :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, even in CS50, arrays of size N have highest legal index N-1 and start at 0.

With your loops

- `i` gets up to `height-1`, correct
- `j` gets up to `width-1`,  correct
- `k` starts at -1, incorrect but the `if` protects
- `m` starts at -1, incorrect but the `if` protects
- `k` gets up to `i+1` which is `heigth`, incorrect and the `if` does not protect either
- `m` gets up to `j+1` which is `width`,  incorrect and the `if` does not protect either

You get the "index 600 out of bounds for type 'RGBTRIPLE [width]" because you access

```
image[k][m].rgbtGreen
```

with `m` being equal to `width`, because of the last bullet point.

That is forbidden because of the first sentence in this answer.

What you need is to change your loops to go from 0 to width-1, especially for the inner loops. For that I would change the outer loops, make them go from 1 to width-2. At that point the protective `if` should become unneeded, it is broken anyway. It should use `<` instead of `<=`.
Then you probably need to treat the picture edges specially.
Same for the height-related parts obviously.